# How to clean a form containing images in android studio

Tags: android

I want clean my form after I submit it. After submitting the display looks clean, but when I submit again the form includes the same photo even though I have taken a different photo.

Here is my code.

```
    public void UploadImageToServer(){
    FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FormPatroli.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {
            super.onPostExecute(string1);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(FormPatroli.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tv_tanggal.setText("");
            tv_jam.setText("");
            tv_id_checkpoint.setText("");
            tv_area.setText("");
            tv_checkpoint.setText("");
            sp_keterangan.setSelection(0);
            tv_uraian_situasi.setText("");
            ShowSelectedImage.setImageResource(0);
            ConvertImage="";
            FixBitmap=null;
            byteArray=null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();
            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
            HashMapParams.put(id, getId);
            HashMapParams.put(tgl_patroli, getTgl_patroli);
            HashMapParams.put(jam, getJam);
            HashMapParams.put(id_checkpoint, getId_checkpoint);
            HashMapParams.put(keterangan, getKeterangan);
            HashMapParams.put(uraian_situasi, getUraian_situasi);

            HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);
            HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);
            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://192.168.137.187/smart/patroli/input.php", HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;


        }
    }
    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
    AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
}
```

Could someone suggest a different method for cleaning the photo / bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

In the postExecute method take the Bitmap object and call recycle(), like this.

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: If it's not working then on post execute method you call finish(). This will close your current activity it will help you.